Skewness and kurtosis for image processing
While running python map reducing code to calculate skewness and kurtosis values i am unable to get output:
Code

import os
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from scipy.stats import skew, kurtosis
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

class MetalImageSkewnessKurtosis(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, input_paths):
        print("Mapper function called")
        metal_folder = r'D:\polluted_project\metals'
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(metal_folder):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".jpeg") or file.endswith(".png"):
                    image_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                    image_name = os.path.basename(image_path)

                    # Load image and convert to grayscale
                    img = Image.open(image_path).convert('L')
                    pixel_values = np.array(img).flatten()

                    # Calculate skewness and kurtosis of the pixel values
                    skewness = skew(pixel_values)
                    kurt = kurtosis(pixel_values)

                    # Emit the image name and its skewness, kurtosis values as key-value pairs
                    yield (image_name, (skewness, kurt)), None

    def reducer(self, key, values):
        print("reducer  function called")
        for value in values:
            print(f"{key}\t{value}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MetalImageSkewnessKurtosis.run()


this is my code
i need output at console

What would you like to do with your images? Can you add sample inputs and expected outputs?

You can do that much more simply for all your files with ImageMagick, using magick *.jpg -colorspace gray -format "%f: %[kurtosis], %[skewness]\n" info:
